# Android Java, How to get the value of class attribute?

Tags: java, class, class-attributes

I want to get the value a class attribute, But I am getting exception : **java.lang.NoSuchFieldException**

Person.class

```
public class Person {

    public static final String name = "person name";

}
```

MainActivity.class

```
...

private void method() {

    Class myClass = Person.class;

    String name = myClass.getField("name");

}

...
```

I am getting a java.lang.NoSuchFieldException exception for the getField method.

I tried these solutions but with no avail ...

1. Change **getField** method to **getDeclaredField**
2. Surround the code by try/catch, and got another error (Incompatible types : java.lang.String and java.lang.reflect.Field)
3. Invalidate Android Studio caches and restart

**I don't Know how to access this value, Any solutions or suggestions are welcomed.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Change getField method to getDeclaredField
>
> Surround the code by try/catch, and got another error (Incompatible
>   types : java.lang.String and java.lang.reflect.Field)

that because `getDeclaredField` will return object of type `Field` not `String`, 
just change your code to this

```
Field field = myClass.getDeclaredField("name");
//do something with field
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the value of the field, you can use the `get(...)` method with a null argument - since it's a static field, it does not require any instance:

```
private void method() {

    Class myClass = Person.class;

    Field field = myClass.getField("name");
    String name = field.get(null);

    Log.d("Test", "field value: " + name);
}
```

In your case, it doesn't matter whether you use `getField(...)` or `getDeclaredField(...)`. You would want to use the latter if you want to grab a field in its superclass or an interface implemented by your class.

For example, if `Person` were to extend from a class that has a field named `sample`, you would need to use `getDeclaredField("sample")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your variable in the class "Person" is static:
   (This is not the best solution in my opinion)
   Explanation: getField method returns a type "field" so you CAN NOT save into a variable from another type without a conversion. 
   YourField.get returns an object so you CAN NOT save into a variable from another type without a conversion.

---

```
try{
    Class _person = Person.class;
    Field field = _person.getField("name");
    Object value = field.get(null);
    String valueString = (String)value; /*The String you are looking for*/
}catch (Exception e) {
    //TODO handle exception
}
```

---

2. If your variable in the class "Person" is static:

---

```
    String valueString = Person.name /*The value you are looking for*/
```

---

3. If your variable isn't static but public:
   IMPORTANT (If you have not set a default value to the variable): 
    In this case the value will be an empty string because you are creating a new instance of your calss. You can set the "person name" in the constructor of your Person class another way you will get an empty string because the variable isn't static.

---

```
    Person _person = new Person();
    String personName = _person.name;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a constant you declared, access it directly with the class name as below,

```
String name = Person.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a static constant. Static means there is only one value at a time possible. Or say it like this: The class attribute 'name' is a **class** attribute, not an object attribute! The attribute belongs to the class!

So you don't need to create an instance of your Person class.

You just can use:

```
String name = Person.name;
```

Remember: this only works cause the name belongs to the class. And it does so, because you declared your name variable static.